# Vendor/assets в Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день. Пытаясь подключить шаблон в своем приложении, я переместил файлы содержащиеся в папке /assets шаблона в vendor/assets приложения, и дописал в application.rb следующее:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("template_folder")
```

все css и js отлично заработали, но только по отношению к пути прописанному в routes.rb как:

```
root to: "pages#index"
```

то есть при заходе на главную страницу.
Когда же я пытаюсь открыть pages/index или pages/contact, css и js не работают. 
Как я могу заставить их работать с другими контроллерами в моем приложении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы, например, javascript, лежащий в `vendor/assets/javascripts/` можно было бы подключить так же, как если бы он лежал в обычном месте, нужно было бы написать `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "javascripts")`.

То, как написано у вас, приводит к тому, что директивы, хелперы, компиляторы ассетов будут искать указанные файлы также и в `<папка приложения>/template_folder`, который, как я понял, пуст.